# add groovy code to grails input form

Tags: forms, url, grails, groovy

Is it possible to add groovy code to grails form?
I have a form:

```
<g:uploadForm controller="document" action="save" method="post">
    <input type="file" name="dataFile" />
    <input type="submit" id="addDocument" value="<g:message code=messages.document.save"/>">
</g:uploadForm>
```

I need to add code that puts the URL segments to the parameter value.

Comment: what do you meean with 'URL segment to the parameter value'?

Comment: You want to send from the actual url to another? Example: showUploadForm?param1=x&param2=y send to document/save?param1=x&param2=y

Comment: Sergio, exactly! And I dont know how to do that

Answer (score 1):

You're using a POST (because it's an upload and that's correct) method in your form, so you will not see the params in the URL. The params will get there (to the controller you redirect the request to), but won't show at the URL. In any case, you should go with hidden inputs in your form. Like:

```
<input type="hidden" id="foo" value=""/>
```

In your controller, you can get the parameters set in your input hidden fields simply by accessing the **params** map:

```
params.foo
```

Answer (score 0):

Use hidden fields inside the form.